# Searching List<Items> then change to List<ItemTypeA : Item>

Tags: c#, search, list

I have this code and i need to be able to search through different lists of `HierarchyItem`s and return a list of the correct type
i.e. `Hierarchy h = new Hierarchy();`
`//add a load of items of HierarchyItemA type;`
`List<HierarchyItemA> results = h.Search("text");`

CODE:

```
public class Hierarchy
{
    private List<HierarchyItem> items;

    public Hierarchy()
    {
        items = new List<T>();
    }
    public void AddItem(HierarchyItem item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }
    public List<T> Search(string searchText)
    {
        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        foreach (HierarchyItem item in items)
        {
            if (item.DisplayText().ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
            {
                results.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
public abstract class HierarchyItem
{
    public string DisplayText()
    {
        //returns a string
    }
}
public class HierarchyItemA : HierarchyItem
{
    //do whatever
}
public class HierarchyItemB : HierarchyItem
{
    //do whatever
}
```

Cheers

EDIT:
there are several hierarchies each one only has one type in it. the Hierarchy.Search(text) should return a list containing items of the correct type (correct being of type A or B)

Comment: Unless the HTML swallowed your < or >, your code does not compile.

Comment: there was a < and > in it but i might have deleted it trying to do something lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand what you're trying to do now. Thanks for clarifying.

First, you need to declare the class `Hierarchy` as generic by replacing `public class Hierarchy` with `public class Hierarchy<T>`. We'll also put a constraint on it that `T` must be a `HierarchyItem`.

```
public class Hierarchy<T> where T : HierarchyItem
```

We'll replace `private List<HierarchyItem> items` with

```
private List<T> items;
```

and `public void AddItem(HierarchyItem item)` with

```
public void AddItem(T item)
```

And finally, the line `foreach (HierarchyItem item in items)` in the method search should be replaced by

```
foreach(T item in items).
```

Thus, we end up with

```
public class Hierarchy<T> where T: HierarchyItem {
    List<T> items;

    public Hierarchy() {
        items = new List<T>();
    }
    public void AddItem(T item) {
        items.Add(item);
    }
    public List<T> Search(string searchText) {
        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        foreach (T item in items) {
            if (item.DisplayText().ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())) {
                results.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

And that should be what you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is this, however Jason's answer is just as correct.

```
 public List<T> Search(string searchText) where T : HierarchyItem
    {
        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        foreach (HierarchyItem item in items)
        {
            if (item.DisplayText().ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
            {
                 T castedItem = item as T;
                 if(castedItem != null )
                      results.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return results; 
    }
```

Comment: Error: The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint

Comment: @harryovers, sorry forgot to add a constraint..edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, way to much code for those other answers. This is a one line problem peeps.

```
public List<T> Search(string searchText) where T: HirearchyItem
    {
        return Items.OfType<T>().Where(t => t.DisplayText.ToUpper().Contains(searchText.ToUpper())).ToList<T>();   
    }
```

But if part of the design is that any Hirearchy can only contain items of a single HirearchyItem type, then you may want to make Hirearchy itself a generic class.

Truth be told, Hirearchy is really just a wrapper for a List, why don't you just create an interface for DisplayText and an extention method for List when T implements IHasDisplayText that performs this search?

Comment: yeah, that is if he is using .NET 3.5, which he didn't specify.

Comment: If he isn't, then he should be. 2.0 blows monkey chunks.

Comment: Note: One liners aren't better, readable code (not for you, but for others) is preferred!